# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Please can someone explain how to fix error that TS throws: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'. In my code i want to show `<Confetti/>` component depending on `isCorrect` value. If var has falsy value i need nothing to render. How to make this type of logic correctly?

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import ReactConfetti from 'react-confetti';
import { useWindowSize } from 'react-use';

interface ConfettiProps {
    isCorrect: boolean;
}

interface WindowDimensions {
    width: number;
    height: number;
  }

const Confetti: FC<ConfettiProps> = ({isCorrect}) => {
    const { width, height }: WindowDimensions = useWindowSize();

  return (
    isCorrect && (<ReactConfetti width={width} height={height}/> )
  )
}

export default Confetti;
```

Comment: I think you cannot just return nothing on a JSX element, or a boolean. I am guessing that isCorrect ? <ReactConfetti> : null would work.

Answer (score 9):

Two options:

```
return (
  isCorrect ? (<ReactConfetti width={width} height={height}/> ) : null
)
```

```
return (
  <>{isCorrect && (<ReactConfetti width={width} height={height}/> )}</>
)
```

`<></>` is a react framgment

Answer (score 7):

I had this error because I was using a `.ts`, not a `.tsx` file. So if you're using a ts file, change the extension to `.tsx`.
I hope this helps!

Comment: that's was right